# C++ generating random numbers

Tags: c++

My output is 20 random 1's, not between 10 and 1, can anyone explain why this is happening?

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <ctime> 
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{ 
    srand((unsigned)time(0)); 
    int random_integer; 
    int lowest=1, highest=10; 
    int range=(highest-lowest)+1; 
    for(int index=0; index<20; index++){ 
        random_integer = lowest+int(range*rand()/(RAND_MAX + 1.0)); 
        cout << random_integer << endl; 
    } 
}
```

> output:
>       1
>       1
>       1
>       1
>       1
>       1
>       1
>       1
>       1
>       1
>       1
>       1
>       1
>       1
>       1
>       1
>       1
>       1
>       1

Comment: i am only able to generate a 1's, no random number generating is acting on my code, i don't know the actual problem in it, please anyone clear my code...

Comment: May I suggest something like `(rand() % range) + lowest` instead?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, your suggestion is really good and it helps, but there is a slight problem, the answer i need is in between 1 and 10, but it produces 0 sometimes and no number 10....

Comment: @Joachim Your suggestion is actually unfortunately really bad, since it makes the random numbers potentially much more biased.

Comment: For a simple application you can neglect this bias entirely. For scientific computation his idea is really bad of course ... like changing the 10th digit of `pi`.

Comment: hey friends, int main() 
    { 
    srand((unsigned)time(0)); 
    int random_integer; 
    int lowest=0, highest=10; 
    int range=(highest-lowest)+1; 
    for(int index=0; index<20; index++){ 
        random_integer = (rand() % range) + lowest/(RAND_MAX + 1.0);
        cout << random_integer << endl; 
    } 
    } "just clear me, i am getting the output from 0 to 10, 11 numbers, but i don't want to get number 10, just numbers 0 to 9, that means 10 random numbers, what should i do"

Comment: @hochl: So I can also neglect the bias for a simple dice application hosted on some hard money casino website? I mean, it is still simple and not scientific.

Comment: Of course not, any serious application should use a good random number source. But for simple stuff like audio track shuffling noone will ever notice the difference.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Because, on your platform, `RAND_MAX == INT_MAX`.

The expression `range*rand()` can never take on a value greater than `INT_MAX`. If the mathematical expression is greater than `INT_MAX`, then integer overflow reduces it to a number  between `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX`. Dividing that by `RAND_MAX` will always yield zero.

Try this expression:

```
random_integer = lowest+int(range*(rand()/(RAND_MAX + 1.0)))
```

Comment: #define catch_of_the_day this

Comment: Note that some values will occur more often than others if you use this method.  It's not mathematically correct.

Answer (score 16):

It's much easier to use the `<random>` library correctly than `rand` (assuming you're familiar enough with C++ that the syntax doesn't throw you).

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::random_device r;
  std::seed_seq seed{r(), r(), r(), r(), r(), r(), r(), r()};
  std::mt19937 eng(seed);

  std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist(1, 10);

  for(int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
    std::cout << dist(eng) << " ";
}
```

Comment: Easier? Hhmmm, that is a hard sell ;-). The big reason to use `<random>` is it gives you the flexibility to slot in different random distributions, such as normal or poisson, and to slot in different number random generators that are either better or quicker.

Comment: Here is an alternative approach using `<random>`: https://gist.github.com/1946214   I have added some comments. It does not require C++11. I hope it shows what is going on.

Comment: Well, harder to get wrong, say. Also more readable and obvious in intent than using `rand()` correctly. Of course you can wrap the code for using `rand()` into a function that makes it just as readable as `<random>` but since `<random>` already exists, why bother?

Comment: I would say it's easier to use this as the reason this question exists is because of the subtle difficulty in converting `rand()` to produce the output you actually need.

Answer (score 11):

```
random_integer = (rand() % 10) + 1
```

That should give you a pseudo-random number between 1 & 10.

Comment: Using `%` is bad for your probability distribution, tough in this case it doesn't matter much.

Comment: ya i know that it's just not the best way to generate a range but it's the simplest one. for more better and complicated one, i prefer @Rob's answer works perfectly

Comment: @hochl Using `%` is actually the preferred method, if you have a decent random number generator.  Regardless of the method, you have to throw some values away, or accept some bias in the results.

Comment: @JamesKanze: And how do you decide which values to throw away if they are all in [0..10)?

Comment: @phresnel You throw away certain outputs from `rand()`, before reducing the range.  If you want one of ten different values, and `rand()` produces a number of values that are not a multiple of ten, you have to throw some away, or return some of the values in the range more often than others.

Comment: @JamesKanze I don't know anyone in the Monte Carlo community who advocates using modulus in this way (either ryoungs example of the two step process you describe). The method in Rob's post is messier to read but correct, and it is *idomatic* so you stop reading it.

Comment: @dmckee If you're doing serious work with random numbers, and the number of different numbers generated by the random isn't an exact multiple of the number of elements you're interested in, you have to throw out some of the generated random numbers, or you introduce a bias.  The people I know who are doing Monte Carlo analysis are generally looking for a `double` result, with as many different values as the generate can give; in this case, of course, you won't use `%`.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Though rejection sampling is suboptimal in many cases. It is great to teach some principles in monte carlo sampling, but to achieve higher performance (i.e. by wasting less results), usually you don't rejection sample on the number generator but transform the number sequences in a way that does not introduce bias (example: when rejection sampling the area of a circle, you waste more than 20% of performance). Thus, I am unsure why you have the impression that `%` is "the preferred method"; usually, all sequences are stretched to [0..1] or [0..1) and then transformed to the range.

Comment: @phresnel If you're generating discrete values (integers, or something which maps to integers), then there is no possible solution which doesn't involve rejecting some values.  You can't put m into n unless n is a multiple of n, if both m and n are integers.  As for why `%` is the preferred method, the only real reason is simplicity: why go from integer to float back to integer when you don't have to?

Comment: Just to throw a few numbers into the discussion:  The bias we are looking at for `RAND_MAX == INT_MAX` and 32-bit integers is 0.00000047 %.  And the percentage of values we would waste using rejection sampling is 0.00000033 %.

Comment: As @Sven points out, if you care about the bias you also care about the quality of your random numbers and would think twice about using `rand()`.

Comment: @JamesKanze: That's of course right. You could statistically smooth the insertion of n values into m slots, however, that would be a far worse solution than modulus and rejection. Of course, another solution is to use a PRNG with state larger than the range of output values, e.g. Mersenne Twister or KISS ([pointers here](http://gitorious.org/picogen/picogen/blobs/master/src/auxiliary/portable_rng/kiss.hh)), so as to "soften" the distribution.

Answer (score 9):

A somewhat late answer, but it should provide some additional
information **if** the quality of the generation is important.  (Not all
applications  need this—a slight bias is often not a problem.)

First, of course, the problem in the original code is the fact that
`range * rand()` has precedence over the following division, and is done
using integer arithmetic.  Depending on `RAND_MAX`, this can easily
result in overflow, with implementation defined results; on all
implementations that I know, if it does result in overflow (because
`RAND_MAX > INT_MAX / range`, the actual results will almost certainly
be smaller than `RAND_MAX + 1.0`, and the division will result in a 
value less than `1.0`.  There are several ways of avoiding this: the
simplest and most reliable is simply `rand() % range + lowest`.

Note that this supposes that `rand()` is of reasonable quality.  Many
earlier implementations weren't, and I've seen at least one where
`rand() % 6 + 1` to simulate a dice throw alternated odd and even.  The
only correct solution here is to get a better implementation of
`rand()`; it has lead to people trying alternative solutions, such as
`(range * (rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0))) + lowest`.  This masks the
problem, but it won't change a bad generator into a good one.

A second issue, **if** the quality of the generation is important, is
that when generating random integers, you're discretizing: if you're
simulating the throw of a die, for example, you have six possible
values, which you want to occur with equal probability.  The random
generator will generate `RAND_MAX + 1` different values, with equal
probability.  If `RAND_MAX + 1` is not a multiple of 6,  there's no
possible way of distributing the values equaly amont the 6 desired
values.  Imagine the simple case where `RAND_MAX + 1` is 10.  Using the
`%` method above, the values 1–4 are twice as likely as the the
values 5 and 6.  If you use the more complicated formula `1 + int(6 *
(rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0)))` (in the case where `RAND_MAX + 1 == 10`,
it turns out that 3 and 6 are only half as likely as the other values.
Mathematically, there's simply no way of distributing 10 different
values into 6 slots with an equal number of elements in each slot.

Of course, `RAND_MAX` will always be considerably larger than 10, and
the bias introduced will be considerably less; if the range is
significantly less than `RAND_MAX`, it could be acceptable.  If it's
not, however, the usual procedure is something like:

```
int limit = (RAND_MAX + 1LL) - (RAND_MAX + 1LL) % range;
            //  1LL will prevent overflow on most machines.
int result = rand();
while ( result >= limit ) {
    result = rand();
}
return result % range + lowest;
```

(There are several ways of determining the values to throw out.  This
happens to be the one I use, but I remember Andy Koenig using something
completely different—but which resulted in the same values being
thrown out in the end.)

Note that most of the time, you won't enter the loop; the worst case is
when `range` is `(RAND_MAX + 1) / 2 + 1`, in which case, you'll still
average just under one time through the loop.

Note that these comments only apply when you need a fixed number of
discrete results.  For the (other) common case of generating a random
floating point number in the range of `[0,1)`, `rand() / (RAND_MAX +
1.0)` is about as good as you're going to get.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you replace `rand()/(RAND_MAX + 1.0)` with `range*double(rand())/(RAND_MAX + 1.0))`. Since my solution seems to give headaches ...

**possible combinations of arguments:**

- `range*rand()` is an integer and overflows.
- `double(range*rand())` overflows before you convert it to double.
- `range*double(rand())` is not overflowing and yields expected results.

My original post had two braces but they did not change anything (results are the same).

Comment: This doesn’t change a thing since the second operand is already a `double`.

Comment: funny the OPs version gives all 1 while with this diff it gives random numbers. Did you try it out?

Comment: The crucial difference is the additional parentheses you used, not the explicit cast to `double`. I should have said that.

Comment: Sorry but I still don't follow you -- for me one problem with his code is that `range*rand()` is overflowing already, converting `rand()` to `double` will avoid this since `double` has 57 bits of precision.

Comment: Apologies. I completely forgot about the `range` multiplier, I just looked at your piece of code and saw a redundant cast. You are right. And thanks for being persistent.

Answer (score 1):

Visual studio 2008 has no trouble with that program at all and happily generates a swathe of random numbers.

What I would be careful of is the /(RAND_MAX +1.0) as this will likely fall foul of integer problems and end up with a big fat zero.

Cast to double before dividing and then cast back to int afterwards

Comment: `RAND_MAX+1.0` **is** a double, according to *usual arithmetic conversions*, C++03, §5, ¶9.

Answer (score 1):

```
(rand() % highest) + lowest + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You are generating a random number (ie `(range*rand()/(RAND_MAX + 1.0))`) whose value is between -1 and 1 (`]-1,1[`) and then casting it to an integer. The integer value of such number is always 0 so you end up with the `lower + 0`

**EDIT:** added the formula to make my answer clearer

Comment: `rand()` returns a number between 0 and `RAND_MAX`.

Comment: @Gandaro: i was not talking about rand() but the statement (range*rand()/(RAND_MAX + 1.0))....

Comment: Okay, everything is fine then. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Probably "10 * rand()" is smaller than "RAND_MAX + 1.0", so the value of your calculation is 0.

Answer (score 0):

It is one of the simplest logics, got it from a blog. in this logic you can limit the random numbers with that given modulus(%) operator inside the for loop, its just a copy and paste from that blog, but any way check it out:

```
// random numbers generation in C++ using builtin functions
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#include <iomanip>

using std::setw;

#include <cstdlib>   // contains function prototype for rand

int main()
{
// loop 20 times
for ( int counter = 1; counter <= 20; counter++ ) {

    // pick random number from 1 to 6 and output it
    cout << setw( 10 ) << ( 1 + rand() % 6 );

    // if counter divisible by 5, begin new line of output
    if ( counter % 5 == 0 )
        cout << endl;

}

return 0;  // indicates successful termination

} // end main
```

- See more at: http://www.programmingtunes.com/generation-of-random-numbers-c/#sthash.BTZoT5ot.dpuf

Answer (score 0):

What about using a condition to check if the last number is the same as the current one? If the condition is met then generate another random number. This solution works but it will take more time though.