# Random Number Generator Within Given Range

Tags: c++, function, random

I'm trying to write a program that uses a function to generate 10 random numbers within a range provided by the user. It seems to work okay, other than the fact that the numbers returned are all 1's:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int rand_int(int min, int max);

int main()
{
    int min, max;

    cout << "Hello user.\n\n"
         << "This program will generate a list of 10 random numbers within a 
         given range.\n"
         << "Please enter a number for the low end of the range: ";
    cin  >> min;
    cout << "You entered " << min << ". \n"
         << "Now please enter a number for the high end of the range: ";
    cin  >> max;

    while(min > max){
        cout << "Error: Your low number is higher than your high number.\n"
             << "Please reenter your high number, or press ctrl + c 
                 to end program.\n";
        cin  >> max;
        cout << endl;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        int rand_int(int min, int max);
        cout << rand_int << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}


int rand_int(int min, int max)
{
    srand(time(0)); // Ensures rand will generate different numbers at different times

    int range = max - min;

    int num = rand() % (range + min);

    return num;
}
```

Comment: You should go back and read up on variable definition and functions calls. Also, don't reseed everytime (especially not with `time(0)` in a tight loop).

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? I have the book right in front of me and it doesn't get very specific on where or how you can call them.

Comment: Try stepping through the code with a debugger, and if you don't have one add prints to the code to show you what is happening.

Comment: This looks like a homework problem, but I think you will find it enlightening to use a debugger to step thru the rand_int function.  I'd break up the `int num = rand() % (range + min);` line so you can see what is going on in there. (Great minds must think alike @brianbeuning)

Comment: This following link got the same issue:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484588/c-generating-random-numbers

Comment: @Emu same symptoms, totally different causes.

Comment: This has been explained [countless times on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/288739/generate-random-numbers-uniformly-over-an-entire-range?rq=1), but do not use modulo arithmetic to restrict the range of output from an RNG. You will skew the distribution of results. Also, seeding the RNG with `time (0)` is not going to do you any favors - `time (0)` has a 1 second granularity. You are basically re-seeding the RNG with the same value if you call `rand_int (...)` frequently.

Comment: The line "int rand_int(int min, int max);" is not the correct way to call a function.

Comment: Put the seeing into your main. Call it 1 time. Don't seed in a loop.

Comment: See here for uniform distribution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195958/how-do-i-scale-down-numbers-from-rand  and here for why rand is bad: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful

Answer (score 4):

Having warnings turned on may have helped here, with `-Wall` flag `gcc` tells us:

```
warning: the address of 'int rand_int(int, int)' will always evaluate as 'true' [-Waddress]
     cout << rand_int << endl;
             ^
```

Although `clang` gives a warning without the need to add flags. You are using a function pointer here and since [std::cout](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout) does not have an [overload](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/ostream) for a function pointer it is selecting the *bool* overload and converting the function pointer to `true`. The calls should be like this:

```
std::cout << rand_int(min, max)  <<std::endl;
```

Although that will not totally fix your issues, you also need to move:

```
srand(time(0));
```

outside your function preferably at the start of your program. Since you are calling `rand_int` ten times very quickly the result of `time(0)` will probably be the same and therefore you will return the same `10` numbers.

This line:

```
int rand_int(int min, int max);
```

in the for loop is just a redeclaration of the function and is not needed.

Although, if *C++11* is an option using the [random header](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) makes way more sense and is much simpler:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;

    std::mt19937 e2(rd());

    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(1,10);

    for (int n = 0; n < 10; ++n) {
            std::cout << dist(e2) << ", " ;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl ;
}
```

If *C++11* is not an option then your should at least check out the [How can I get random integers in a certain range?](http://c-faq.com/lib/randrange.html)  C FAQ entry which gives the following formula for generating numbers in the range `[M, N]`:

> M + rand() / (RAND_MAX / (N - M + 1) + 1)

and of course there is always boost:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/random/mersenne_twister.hpp>
#include <boost/random/uniform_int_distribution.hpp>

int main()
{
  boost::random::mt19937 gen;
  boost::random::uniform_int_distribution<> dist(1, 10);

  for (int n = 0; n < 10; ++n) {
    std::cout << dist(gen) << ", ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    int rand_int(int min, int max);
    cout << rand_int << endl;
}
```

to:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    int myRandomNumber = rand_int(int min, int max);
    cout << myRandomNumber << endl;
}
```

It seems that you were outputting the function rather than the return result of it.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have to go with the rand method because its for an assignment. I keep getting a parse error on the first line of the for-loop body. "Parse error before ',' "

Comment: @Bobby OK. Focus on the first part of my answer. I have removed the unnecessary part.

Answer (score 0):

The **Fastest & Simplest** way to get the Random Number within a range is-

```
int lower=1,upper=10;//for example
srand(time(0));
int y = (rand() % (upper-lower + 1)) + lower;
```

It will give you the output in the range- [1,10] (both inclusion).

That's it. Cheers!